# Verifying that $\lim_{x\to0}\sin x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\cos x=1$ via squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

Given that $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $\sin x<x$, I have 
$$
0<\sin x<x,
$$
whereby I can conclude that $\lim_{x\to0}\sin x=0$, as desired.

In the course of my work, I also established the following chain of inequalities (with the condition that $x\in(0,\pi/2))$:
\begin{align}
\sin x<x<\tan x
&\iff \sin x\cdot\cos x<x\cos x<\sin x\\[1em]
&\iff \frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\cos x<\cos x<\frac{\sin x}{x}
\end{align}
I know that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, but I still cannot see how to effectively use the squeeze theorem above to conclude that $\lim_{x\to0}\cos x=1$. Does anyone have an insight?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? +1 to compensate.

Comment: You may note that $\cos x=1-2\sin^{2}(x/2)$ and then use the fact that $\sin(x/2)\to 0$. Or if you prefer Squeeze then above relation combined with $\sin x<x$ gives $1-(x^{2}/2)<\cos x<1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I must be missing something very obvious, but how does your chain of inequalities follow from $\cos x=1-2\sin^2(x/2)$ and $\sin x<x$? Did you use the fact that $\sin x$ is increasing on the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ but is less than $x$? I realize I'm missing some obvious manipulation it seems like.

Comment: Just note that $2\sin^{2}(x/2)<2(x/2)^{2}=x^{2}/2$ and hence $\cos x=1-2\sin^{2}(x/2)>1-(x^{2}/2)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for pointing out the error in my ways. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$ and $\sin x < x \implies \sin^2x < x^2$ (for the domain under consideration) to conclude that:

$1 - \cos^2 x < x^2 \implies \cos^2 x > 1 - x^2$

You also know that $\cos^2 x \leq 1$.

Squeeze: $1 - x^2 < \cos^2 x \leq 1$ then take the square root.

Answer (score 0):

sin x is between - x and x 
cos x is between $(1-\frac {x^2}{2})$ and 1 (by cos x expansion)

$-x \leq sin x \leq x \implies $ by squeeze theorem we get limit sinx = 0  as x -> 0

$(1-\frac {x^2}{2}) \leq cos x \leq 1$. Apply squeeze therem at x = 0 , we get desired result